# how to use history instance while using react routers v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6 and I have to use history instance.

I've installed it using

```
yarn add history react-router-dom@next
```

One way of using history instance I guess it must be with v5 is to use useHistory hook imported from react-router-dom

this code is running fine with v5 but with v6 it is not working

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
        history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
};
```

with v6 version, I'm having this error

Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `useNavigate` hook and new [navigate API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#use-navigate-instead-of-history).

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
        navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// import

const { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()

navigate({ pathname: './webpage/path' }) 

navigate({ pathname: './webpage/path' }, { replace: true })
```